# PowerBI (DAX) SELECTEDVALUED for creating a new column

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a visual with a filter (SUPPLIER)

On a table, I would like to create a new column with containing dinamic values for each row, as follows:

```
SELECTED = IF (SELECTEDVALUE(Table[Supplier])=Table[Supplier], "YES", "NO")
```

Basically, I would like to be able to change "YES" and "NO" by changing value on filter "Table[Supplier]".

What I get instead, is that everything is "NO".

There's no connection problems because I have only a table.

Do you know a way to get the result I would like to get?

My final scope is to create a "Legend" (YES/NO) for a map visual that compares gives an hint about % of € related to a supplier (YES) compared to other suppliers (NO)

Comment: Calculated columns cannot be dynamically responsive to slicers since tables are only computed when the data is loaded or refreshed, not in response to user interactions with visuals.

Comment: is there a work-around to reach that goal? 

For example how someone can create a piechart that compare selected value (vale on slicer) to "all the rest"

Comment: Can you provide some input data and the expected one ?

Comment: The "workaround" is to use measures, which are dynamically responsive.